# Asp.net Core 2 Identity Login session lost on Service Fabric Cluster multi machine

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-2.0

Asp.net Core 2 app hosted on Service Fabric, with 1 node type of 5 Virtual machines in a Virtual Machine Scale Set.

In local all works perfectly, but when the app is live, after the login, while browsing the pages (where the authentication is required) **asks again for the login, multiple times losing the authentication session**. It stops for a while after 4 or 5 logins.
Also the "remember me feature" does not work and the session last for like 10 minutes.

I think this has something to do with the app being hosted on multiple machines, it's like any single machine requires it's own login.

I did hours of researches, changing the cookie settings, using the SameSiteMode.None and Sliding expiration but couldn't figure it out, I suspect all the machines in the farm must have the same machine key for decrypting the authentication cookie.
Do I have to set a single Machine Key to make this work? How do I do that?

This is my config code in startup:

```
 services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            // Password settings
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 4;

            // Lockout settings
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 15;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;

            // User settings
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Cookie settings
            options.Cookie.Name = "LoginCookie";
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12);
            options.LoginPath = "/Console/Account/Login";
            options.LogoutPath = "/Console/Account/Logout";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Console/Account/AccessDenied";
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });
```

Comment: Is data protection set up for multiple machines? It sounds like each machine can't decrypt cookies from the others. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction

Comment: Umh no I didn't set up data protection. The topic seems vast and I'll research it. Do you have an example or link that apply to asp.net Core 2 identity?

Comment: Here's a more direct link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: The main limit is you have to store your keys in a shared location across the servers like a file share.

Answer (score 0):

I've analogical issue ASP.NET Core 2 mvc with identity.app hosted on shared hosting.User lost identity unexpected. Locally it works very fine. Here is my Startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<GanDrorIdentityDb>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("GanDror")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<GanDrorIdentityDb>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();



        services.Configure<SMPTConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("SMTPConfigSection"));
        // Configure Identity
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(identityOptions =>
        {

            // Password settings
            identityOptions.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            identityOptions.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            identityOptions.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            identityOptions.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            identityOptions.Password.RequireLowercase = false;

            //    // Lockout settings
            identityOptions.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            identityOptions.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;

            // User settings
            identityOptions.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

        });



        // Cookie settings
        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(100);
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login");
                options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOut");
                .options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
            });

        //var environment = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();


        //services.AddDataProtection()
        //        .SetApplicationName($"my-app-{environment.EnvironmentName}")
        //        .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo($@"{environment.ContentRootPath}\keys"));

        //  services.AddDataProtection();
        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        });

        // Add application services.
        services.AddScoped<IRepository<User>, UserRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IRepository<Photo>, PhotoRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IRepository<GanActivity>, ActivityRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IRepository<CategoryActivity>, CategoryRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public  void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)// RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
       // loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        //loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())


            {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        var options = new RewriteOptions()
  .AddRedirectToHttps();

        app.UseRewriter(options);
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        //app.UseMvc(routes =>
        //{
        //    routes.MapRoute(
        //        name: "default",
        //        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        //});

        CreateRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Azure load balancer configuration:
Ensure that "Client IP and protocol" is set als session persistence in the rules for your endpoints (ssl and non ssl)

Comment: This is not an attempt to answer the question. Once you earn sufficient reputation, you can comment on any post.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a look on settings that are different between the ServiceFabric env and the local one.

I had similar issue which I spent hours to understand. Finally it was a [ValidIssuer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.validissuer?view=azure-dotnet) property that was set from a setting file (Settings.xml as a default values and ApplicationManifest.xml which is loaded only on ServiceFabric env). The default value in Settings.xml was correct but the ApplicationManifest.xml value was wrong, thus validation failed and HttpContext.User was set to anonymous unauthenticated WindowsPrincipal.